# Python Error 1 in My Code don't know why my code won't run

Tags: python, instagram

```
from instabot import Bot

my_instagram_bot=Bot()
#login
my_instagram_bot.login(username="", password="")

#follow a user
my_instagram_bot.follow("python_app_projects")

#follow multiple users
my_instagram_bot.follow_users(["coding_for_beginners_", "python.app", "py_beginners"])

#unfollow the non followers
my_instagram_bot.unfollow_non_followers()
```

Question 1: My code is showing error code 1

```
File "C:\Users\MONEY GETTAZENT\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api.py", line 199, in load_uuid_and_cookie
return load_uuid_and_cookie(self, load_uuid=load_uuid, load_cookie=load_cookie)
File "C:\Users\MONEY GETTAZENT\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api_login.py", line 352, in load_uuid_and_cookie
cookie_username = self.cookie_dict["ds_user"]
KeyError: 'ds_user'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Question:2 I'm looking to add time on how long my bot can follow and unfollow people on instagram.

I attempted to execute my code, but an error 1 message appeared. I also changed the file name from what I had given the bot inside my code, performed a sfc /scanme, removed the path file, and tried again, but the problem message persists.`

Comment: The stack trace you provide does not refer to the code you've shown in your question.  Was there more to the stack trace?  If the code you show is causing that error, you should have gotten a stack trace that refers to one of the lines in your code, the line that is directly leading to the error.

Comment: @CryptoFool when I get home I will let you know if there is another code showing up

Comment: @CryptoFool in Pycharm it just shows exit code 2 :\Python\python.exe "C:/Users/MONEY GETTAZ ENT/PycharmProjects/new.py/main.py" 
C:\Python\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\MONEY GETTAZ ENT\\PycharmProjects\\new.py\\main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @CryptoFool C:\Python\python.exe "C:/Users/MONEY GETTAZ ENT/Desktop/main.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MONEY GETTAZ ENT\Desktop\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from instabot import Bot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'instabot'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: These errors are more fundamental than the one you show in your question (you should update your question to contain these errors and to provide the current status of your problem).  Your first error suggested that your code was running.  These two errors suggest your code now isn't even getting started.  What changed?

Comment: `\\new.py\\main.py` at the end of the path mentioned in the first error is particularly strange.  This suggests that you have a directory named `new.py` that contains a Python file named `main.py`.  My guess is that this isn't what is actually going on in your filesystem.  That's probably a config problem.  The second error suggests that the "instabot" package isn't installed in the version of Python you're using to run your app.

Comment: @CryptoFool I did was deleted any duplicate file I had made for my code inside of Pycharm